# Get webroot in PHP

Tags: php

I am using Apache server for [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). How can I retrieve my web root in PHP, like `http://localhost/testthesis/`?

Answer (score 16):

#### Absolute path on the local server (from the client's perspective)

For the local links on your site simply use the root directory, which is always just `/`. So you can make it

```
$folder = '/';
```

or even without any variable, simply start any address from `/`.

For the currently requested address use

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

#### The full URL (from the client's perspective)

For the root of your web-server

```
$protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ?? '') === 'on' ? 'http://' : 'https://';
$folder = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
```

For the current requested address

```
$protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ?? '') === 'on' ? 'http://' : 'https://';
$folder = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
$web_root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/";

OUTPUT -->http://website.com/parent_folder/
```

Comment: Becareful, in mod_rewrite scenarios, php_self will always return the root script you are directing your traffic to, it may not be always true.

Answer (score 7):

Web root is **always** just `/`. You'd never need the hostname or protocol part, and root can be only root of the server, not some folder or file.

If you need some path, like `/testthesis/` - there are ways, but it has nothing common with web **root**.

If you need a filesystem directory for the webroot - it's in the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is not a webroot but rather a URL.

You can get your current URL like so:

```
$protocol = strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE'], '443') !== false ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```