# php - file_get_contents() is empty but content is present

Tags: php

I generate an image based in data uri within a simple php script. The path to the file works fine when used inside an image tag. I am trying to download this image using php `zip`. It is currently failing due to content is empty.

Works fine:

```
$image2 = "http://cdn.screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Star-Wars-Logo-Art.jpg";
echo file_get_contents( $image2 ); // returns content to screen
```

Fails:

```
$image2 = "/myPath/myPath1/script.php";
echo file_get_contents( $image2 ); // nothing displayed
```

If I put this path inside an image tag on the screen it's fine

```
<img src="/myPath/myPath1/script.php" />
```

`script.php` Script used to generate image

```
$imgstr = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/........... rest of string";
if (!preg_match('/data:([^;]*);base64,(.*)/', $imgstr, $matches)) {
die("error");
}

// Decode the data
$content = base64_decode($matches[2]);

// Output the correct HTTP headers
header('Content-Type: '.$matches[1]);
//header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); // tried this made no difference

// Output the actual image data
echo $content;
```

I have tried everything and seem to be going around in circles. Any advice is very much welcomed.

Comment: `echo file_get_contents( $image2 )` will display the contents of the php file, not the server rendered version. You need CURL or include.

Comment: Absolute local filesystem references (those beginning with a `/`) are based on filesystem root, not on the webserver root

Comment: What @MarkBaker is saying is concat your `http://yourdomain.com` to $image2 and you will be good to go

Comment: @MarkBaker is correct. Take a look at this answer and see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2425163/25515

Comment: I have tried using a full domain path but I just get a loading screen and nothing happens and eventually just crashes. But is i go to the url directly the image is displayed.

Comment: Where is `script.php` located on the server, and where is the file with the `echo file_get_contents( $image2 );` snippet it located ?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning as I said in the comment below the only answer here. That path on your server doesn't necessarily reflect the path on your filesystem. PHP internally uses the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
<img src="/myPath/myPath1/script.php" />
```

HTML tag, causes the **execution** of the file that **corresponds** to the `/myPath/myPath1/script.php` querystring.

The file can be located any where on the server, depending on your apache/nginx and `.htaccess` configuration.

On the other hand,

```
$image2 = "/myPath/myPath1/script.php";
echo file_get_contents( $image2 )
```

Tries to read to the **contents** of the file **located** on that specific path

If you want to execute that file, and you know the path to it:

```
$image2 = "/myPath/myPath1/script.php";
ob_start();
include $image2;
$contents=ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: I have just tried this. Nothing is displayed on screen and a var_dump of $contents returns `string(0) ""`

Comment: are you sure you have the correct path to the script file ?

Comment: I think the comments need to be combined to form the correct answer. This is correct, however, is the path to your script correct from the file running this script? Within your PHP file you need to build the path differently.

Comment: @mouser I have used full path including htt://www.domain.com and also `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, It will be much easier to help you if we knew to full paths to those two files (`script.php` and the file with the `file_get_contents`)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning To elaborate on Uri Goren's comment: E.g.: `script.php` is in `e:\scripts\image\script.php` while the calling script is in `e:\scripts\callingscript.php` the correct file path for script.php for the include becomes: `image/script.php`.

Comment: @UriGoren my file with get contents is `www.mydomain.com/folderA/myFile.php` and the othe file is located `www.mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/script.php`

Comment: then your path should be `$image2='../folder1/folder2/folder3/script.php';`

Comment: Thanks but know my path is correct as with an include it works ok. The issue is with `file_get_contents()`