# how to PHP redirect to the root index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, header

So I have this three sub folders. That folders stands for the three users. I have this `session.php` this will check if the users 'id' is available it will continue to login, but if now it will redirect you to `index.php`

Here is my code to `session.php`

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();
//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || (trim($_SESSION['username']) == '')) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
$session_id=$_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

I know the code is correct and my only problem is the header();
For example, when I type location/rootFolder/SubFolder/file.php

It will give me PHP error Object not found or the file is not existing

Comment: You absolutely need to show a subset of the code that produces the error from `location/rootFolder/SubFolder/file.php` or otherwise you could get more bad answers than lottery combinations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get webroot in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424606/get-webroot-in-php)

Comment: just add a `/` before `index.php`.  `header("Location: /index.php")`

Comment: if your current page and next page present in same directory means no need any / slashes otherwise you can go back single directory by ../file.php  or go back two directory by ../../file.php like this

Comment: `header("Location /index.php")` is not working

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to prefix your relative URI with a `/` like so:
`header('Location: /index.php');`

---

**Updated**

The URL that is redirected to is not relative to the script, it is relative to the current user's URL.
So if `session.php` is in `/system/functions/session.php`

and the current URL is `http:://example.com/user/subfolder/file.php`

- `header('Location: index.php');` will redirect to `http:://example.com/user/subfolder/index.php`
- `header('Location: ../index.php');` will redirect to `http:://example.com/user/index.php`
- `header('Location: ../../index.php');` will redirect to `http:://example.com/index.php`
- `header('Location: /index.php');` will redirect to `http:://example.com/index.php`
- `header('Location: /');` will redirect to `http:://example.com/`

So in order to get to `location/rootFolder/SubFolder/file.php` if it can be found at `http://example.com/SubFolder/file.php`

You would use `header('Location: /SubFolder/file.php');`

This is assuming `rootFolder` is your webserver `DOCUMENT_ROOT` as can be viewed in `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

Comment: @AdrianPascuaVivsTV updated with a breakdown on how relative paths work.

Comment: @AdrianPascuaVivsTV if you meant `location` is actually `localhost` in your question, please update your question to read `localhost` as we are thinking that it is a physical file location.

Answer (score 1):

Use below:

```
header("location: /");
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to move from inside folder to outside folder index page then in that case you can use:

```
header("location:../index.php");
```

Comment: can you elaborate...you want to go from where to where

Comment: for example i type localhost/RootFolder/SubFolder/file.php instead of localhost/Rootfolder/index.php this is where i get the file does not exist

Comment: and where is session.php located?

Comment: in the root folder

Answer (score 0):

As your index is in parent dir use: `header("Location: ../index.php");`

If your `index.php` is in root dir: `header("Location: /index.php");`

Using `/` may throw errors so better way: `header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/index.php");`

Comment: in the URL i type localhost/rootfolder/subfolder/file.php

Comment: @AdrianPascuaVivsTV If you get a file not found for that, then the file doesn't exist. Recheck path.

Answer (score 0):

if your current page and next page present in same directory means no need any `/` slashes otherwise you can go back single directory by `../file.php` or go back two directory by `../../file.php` like this